# Find correct tty & tty settings

Tags: linux, serial-port, serial-console

I managed to run pure Debian (debootstraped) ON my Android-based device. That means that my Nexus 5 runs a perfectly normal GNU/Linux system but with the CyanogenMod 11 Linux kernel (has some model-specific patches).

I have serial connection to the phone (through 4-pin modded headphone jack) and I can see the full kernel log.

The problem is that although the system DOES boot and work I can't find a way to interface with it, as I can't find the correct tty settings I need to use.

First of all the system is for sure alive, as I put something like `/sbin/ls /dev > /hello` in the inittab (where the getty should be) and I got the directory listing.

The serial port is on /dev/ttyHSL0 and I've tried a lot with getty and the last is `/sbin/getty -8 -L -m -w 115200 ttyHSL0` with no luck at all. I've tried the other 2 ports that the listing reported (tty1 & ttyS0) without any luck as well...

Note: I tried to initiate WiFi on boot so I can get SSH but it did not work, it would not connect to the network and I don't know why. When I have a bash prompt, I'll be able to debug it...

Note 2: This is NOT a chroot system, it's Debian running on the device purely. This has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: seems like you might want to look at a [netconsole](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole) kernel parameter config and eschew the jtagged headphone jack thing - at least for `dmesg`.

Comment: with an android device? How am I going to set up a receiver?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - you mean because you are mobile or because the WiFi if is not up in time? I think the second problem is only a matter of which modules get compiled in.

Comment: The wifi is not functional and I can't debug it. Also there is no "ethernet" interface. I solved the problem though, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after a lot of debugging (and head banging against the wall) in the init script that I was using to switch_root to the directory where debian is, I did not mount /dev, /proc and /sys...

The correct tty was actually `1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty ttyHSL0 115200`